# OSX binary couchDB fails to verify and fails on views with exit_status, 1

Tags: macos, couchdb

After downloading and starting the couchDB server/app , the verification test and all views return an error starting with this :

```
{{badmatch,{error,{bad_return_value,{os_process_error,{exit_status,1}}}}}
```

couchDB version is 1.3.0

I am running OSX 10.8.3
Do I need to build from source? 
I prefer the binary version if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The binary couchDB is distributed as a standalone app. When you execute it, it will start the couchDB services which will now run as a service that you can find in your task manager under "apache couchDB".

If you open the app / start the server, and then want to move the app into a more convenient location (for instance your app folder), you must shut down the service that is running.

If you move it without shutting down the server, you will get the error as described in the question.

So the solution is to simply terminate the running service from the task manager, move the couchDB app and then start it again. It should now work as expected.